# By vs to - which one is natural and why, in "Come __ my office"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, prepositions, difference

> Come by my office vs Come to my office

Usage of "by" in this way (Is natural or not?)

I found one sense of **by** is **to**.
Can i use them  interchangeably?

Comment: This may depend on dialect.  Where I live, _come to_ would be more common than _come by_.  I believe there are other places where _come by_ might be more common.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The literal meaning of both expressions is either an invitation or an order to come to that person's office, depending on the relationship between the two people.

The difference between the two is that "come by" has a casual feeling of "*come and visit for something not serious at some time*", whereas "come to" has no nuance, so it could mean the same as "come by...", or it could mean "*come immediately for something serious*". What the other person understands from "*Come to my office*" would depend highly on the context. If your boss says this to you without context or other qualifier, you might feel nervous.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I've always assumed that "come by", "stop by", etc. originated from "come in _when you're passing by_",  whereas "come to" definitely implies a specific journey being made.  As you say, either can be an invitation or a command, and you need the context to determine which.

Comment: @TobySpeight - A linguist friend observed that the phenomena of substituting *by* for *to* and also *at* is largely limited to the Midwestern U.S.  She suggested that this could be a Germanic influence on English where the German word **bei** (which sort of means *at*) was historically used and subsequently adopted by all speakers due to the crossover in pronunciation.  Don't know if it's true but I found it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the phrase is natural and idiomatic. And no you can't use them interchangeably. "by" means you go "near" that place while "to" is usually "at" or "inside" the place. But I'm pretty sure "to" is used more in this case than "by", an alternative would be "meet me **outside** my office".

Comment: In dictionary it's meaning **to** is given, then what   i should prefer?

Comment: @Sam It always depends on context! :)

Comment: Since OP is asking about “come by my office” as an alternative to “come **to** my office,” the context is probably, “come visit,” not “meet me near.”

Comment: "come by" , "stop by" and "drop by" are all idiomatic expressions which mean come to, but with a casual, non-urgent connotation. They would not normally be used to mean to come near the office.